# How do I copy an initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++11

The following doesn't output anything for me. From what I understand, the lifetime of an initializer_list is very limited and that copying an initializer_list doesn't copy the underlying elements. I thought that passing by value would allow a move, and even an explicit move doesn't work. I can't bind it to a reference and using a separate reference variable doesn't work here. Even using a vector doesn't work??

```
template <typename T, typename Pred>
void for_each(T t, const Pred& pred)
{
    auto local = std::vector<typename T::value_type>{t.begin(), t.end()};

    for (typename decltype(local)::size_type i = 0; i < local.size(); ++i)
        pred(*(i + std::begin(local)));
}

void pred(char c)
{
    std::cout << c << " ";
}

int main()
{
    auto arr { 1, 2, 3 };
    for_each(arr, pred);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You see nothing because neither 0x01, 0x02 nor 0x03 are printable chars

Answer (score 3):

Your predicate is wrong : you pass it `int` values, not `char`, so your predicate is passed the characters 0x01, 0x02 and 0x03, which are not printable.

You could use :

```
void pred(int c)
{
    std::cout << c << " ";
}
```

And your code now works [fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2ca6fda9744b2aa).

You could also just write a function template:

```
template<typename T>
void pred(T c)
{
    std::cout << c << " ";
}
```

---

**Note:**

Consider writing your loop with a for-range :

```
for (auto&& v : t)
    pred(v);
```